# Cannot upload big files (videos) using laravel filemanager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-manager

I did a lot of research about this issue, but still not working. I have installed a package [`laravel-filemanager`](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) for my `laravel5.1` project. If I upload big files (e.g. 20MB and up sized videos), it gives me an error `File is too big`. I've also edited my `php.ini`. Please see my settings below:

**`php.ini`**

```
upload_max_filesize: 250MB    
post_max_size: 250MB
```

Comment: Did you restart your webserver (e.g. `apache2`) after modifying `php.ini`?

Comment: @Quezler Yes...

Comment: In your controller add this and paste the error message here. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
 `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: @Saurabh Can you explain it explicitly?

Comment: You must be processing the upload request with a controller right? Inside your controller paste these code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` It will show you what is the exact error. I am guessing the `memory_limit` is the issue here

Comment: @Saurabh Have you tried to use that package before?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: Have you published the config files for the package and changed the "max_file_size" ? https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config

. Have you confirmed your php.ini changes have worked by checking the `php_info();` output after rebooting your webserver?

Comment: try running `php artisan cache:clear  `

Comment: you can check your ini options using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` call at the top of your public/index.php file. It’ll show you what php.ini is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

How about changing php.ini to this.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize = 1024M
php_value post_max_size = 1024M
php_value memory_limit = 1024M
```